# Build JSON from object PlayFramework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

To build JSON from scala `case class` using Play ScalaJson (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson) I have to either manual construct `JsObject` or implement `implicit Writes` (that actually means also manual work).

While using lift-web json lib I can define `implicit f Formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats` and all transformation will be done in background.

Is any way how scala case classes can be easily transformed in json with play framework json lib ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the macro to define the instances or `OWrites[T]`, `Reads[T]` or `OFormat[T]` for any case class `T`.

```
implicit val writes: Writes[T] = play.api.libs.json.Json.writes[T]
// Same for Reads or OFormat
```

Since the `OFormat` or the `OWrites` is defined (available as implicit), the `.toJson` can be used.

```
val jsValue: JsValue = Json.toJson(instanceOfT)
```

To keep the object specificity, that's to say having the `JsValue` typed as `JsObject`, the `.writes` can be called directly.

```
val jsObj: JsObject = implicitly[OWrites[T]].writes(instanceOfT)
// works even if a OFormat is defined, as 'compatible'
```

Since the `OFormat` or the `Reads` is defined, the `.fromJson` can be used.

```
val t: JsResult[T] = Json.fromJson[T](jsValue)
```

Comment: It does not work for me. 1) `implicit Writes[T]` - what if I have case class with property as another case class `case class P(val c: Node1)`... I need implicits for both of them ?

Comment: Of course. You have to decide/code how each type (top level or embedded) should be handled: by default typeclass instances provided by macros or by custom impl.

Comment: that what I was talking about. In `lift-json` there is default formatter. I do not need to code anything.

Comment: That's how typeclass system works, you have to decide which instance you want for which type, even if that the default behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is using Play Json containing helper functions to handle JsValues, and define an implicit format in the companion object of the model. This format will be used implicitly in both serialization and deserialization. Below is an example.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class User(name: String, age: Int)

object {
  implicit val format = Json.format[User]
}
```

For a more comprehensive example, please take a look at this repository:https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/app/models/User.scala